# Integrating Count.ly To Android Application

Tags: java, android, countly-analytics

I want to use [Count.ly](http://count.ly) with my Android app. I'm newbie on Android. There is an installation documentation [here](http://count.ly/resources/installation/android) but i couldn't follow these steps.

**1) I've added this to my manifest file, inside `<application>`**

```
<service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**2) Added this to my MainActivity's onCreate() method.**

```
OpenUDID_manager.sync(getApplicationContext());

        if(OpenUDID_manager.isInitialized())
        {
            String oudid = OpenUDID_manager.getOpenUDID();

        }
```

But i'm stuck at next step . What they mean with

> Add Countly.java to your project under Eclipse.

? Just i should copy Countly.java to my */src/com/blabla/appname* folder?

Also i don't know what should i do after this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. It was my mistake. I don't need to init OpenUDID on my project.

I just add these to my activity

```
@Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Countly.sharedInstance().onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        Countly.sharedInstance().onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

and this to onCreate()

`Countly.sharedInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), "https://cloud.count.ly", "...");`

And lastly copied `src/org/*` directory to  my src dir , `Countly.java`file to my package.

Answer (score -1):

Going by the guide. It looks like they do indeed want it copied to your project so that you can call its methods. All you need to do is plant it in the project.

Call its methods by using Countly. to call the class file.

Also don't forget to set up INTERNET permissions.

Comment: probably i should import it as library, because if i copy-paste it, i need to change package name etc. I need step by step help. This answer isn't enough for me.

Comment: If by package name you mean the very first line in Countly.java then just rewrite it so its the package it is currently in. For the rest you'll have to be more clear, have you tried importing it? What happens?